# Php ftp_connect fails, FTP client connects

Tags: php, ftp

(this question might not belong here, but on ServerFault, I don't know exactly where the problem comes from)

I'm trying to connect to an FTP server like this:

```
$con = ftp_connect( '86.xxx.xx.xxx', 21 ) or die("FTP connect error");
```

and it always throws me the error message.

I can connect like this to other FTP servers, but not this one. I can also connect to this one via an FTP client.

What server settings could be wrong that permit a client connect but not PHP?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: if you `SSH` to your server, can you open `FTP` to that IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my host was blocking remote FTP access to other servers. Oddly enough it allowed me to connect to my other servers at this host.